# What happens if rsnapshot / rdiff-backup gets interrupted in the middle of a transfer?

Tags: backup, rsync, home-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if rsnapshot / rdiff-backup gets interrupted in the middle of a transfer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6663/what-happens-if-rsnapshot-rdiff-backup-gets-interrupted-in-the-middle-of-a-tra)

**What happens if rsnapshot or rdiff-backup gets interrupted in the middle of a transfer?**

I know that rsnapshot tries to make a complete snapshot of your system in rotating fashion, and rdiff-backup makes a differential backup, which is going to be based on the files previously saved behind it.

So: What happens if it gets interrupted in the middle?

**Does this result in an "incomplete snapshot"?**

Will other snapshots which are dependent on this one be corrupted?  (Surely not, but... ? ... I am new to backup systems.)

Furthermore, I **have set this up on a laptop to be backed up from home server**, when I'm at home on home network, so there should be lots of opportunities for the server to **not** get a chance to finish the transfer before ending the connection. (This is an on ubuntu server.)